# Group homomorphism and normality of the image of a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, $f \colon G \rightarrow H$ a homomorphism, and $M \unlhd G$. Denote by $N_H(X)$ the normalizer in $H$ of some $X \le H$. Is it true that $f(G)<H \Rightarrow N_H(f(M))<H$ ?

Comment: What you're asking is trivially true. I assume you mean to ask whether $N_H(f(M)) <f(G) $, and the answer is no to that.

Comment: Why is it trivially true?

Comment: @Matt Samuel: maybe using "$<$" in place of "$\lneqq $" was somehow misleading; the latter is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in general. Suppose for example that $G$ has trivial centre, and take $M=G$, $H = \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Let $f$ be the map which sends an element of $G$ to the automorphism that is conjugation by it. Then $f(G) = \operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is normal in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and if $\lvert \operatorname{Out}(G)\rvert >1$ then $f(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Thank you, really. What if we furtherly constraint by assuming $M$ to be a proper (normal) subgroup of $G$?

Comment: That's not going to change anything.

Comment: Does it mean that a couter-example with $M \ne G$ can be shown, that contradicts the conjectured implication in the question? Basically, I'd like to know whether the surjectivity of $f$ is also *necessary* to ensure that the image of any *proper* normal subgroup of $G$ is normal in the whole $H$.
I'm hoping not be losing myself in the logical implications...

Comment: Yes, and it's easy to find counterexamples. Take your favourite abelian group $A$ and your second-favourite abelian group $B$. Can you find an $f : A \to A \times B$ that does what you want?

Comment: The following choice should do the job: $A=B=(\mathbb{Z},+)$, $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $l \mapsto (l,2l)$, where "$\times$" stands for the direct product, and $M=2\mathbb{Z} \unlhd \mathbb{Z}$ such that $M \ne \mathbb{Z}$. In fact, $f(l+g)=(l+g,2l+2g)=(l,2l)*(g,2g)=f(l)*f(g)$, so $f$ is a homomorphism; finally, $f(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z} \lneqq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, but $f(2\mathbb{Z}) \unlhd \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ being this latter abelian. Is it what you hinted above?